# Note taking applications which keeps on screen while fullscreen inside game? (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, software-recommendation, games, fullscreen

So, I like to keep tracks of an economy inside a game, but it's kinda annoying to always have to exit full screen to see my notes. So I'm looking for a note taking app which stays on-screen, even if I go full screen in my game. I tried XPad (Kubuntu) but it does not work the way as I wanted it. It doesn't stay on screen when I'm fullscreen in-game.

Comment: Can you set the game to run as fullscreen-windowed? Then set the other window as "always on top" via the window settings (alt+f2 or right-click the icon at the top-left of the window)? Is there a specific game that you're wanting this to work for?